# Need Explanation with Probability Problem from textbook

Tags: probability

I am going through probability exercise in a [book](https://leanpub.com/openintro-statistics), and kinda disagree with the reasoning provided by the solution. The answer however is the same. Here is the problem

In a classroom with 24 students, 7 students are wearing jeans, 4 are wearing shorts, 8
are wearing skirts, and the rest are wearing leggings. If we randomly select 3 students without replacement,
what is the probability that one of the selected students is wearing leggings and the other two are wearing
jeans?

I know this is asking $P(1 leggings \cap 2 jeans)$, which consists of

- $P(A) = P(pick1=\mathbf{legging} \cap pick2=jeans \cap pick3=jeans)$
- $P(B) = P(pick1=jeans \cap pick2=\mathbf{legging} \cap pick3=jeans)$
- $P(C) = P(pick1=jeans \cap pick2=jeans \cap pick3=\mathbf{legging})$

So, I have to add $P(A) + P(B) + P(C)$.

- $P(A) = P(pick1=\mathbf{legging} \cap pick2=jeans \cap pick3=jeans) = {5\over22} * {6\over23} * {7\over24}$
- $P(B) = P(pick1=jeans \cap pick2=\mathbf{legging} \cap pick3=jeans) = {6\over22} * {5\over23} * {7\over24}$
- $P(C) = P(pick1=jeans \cap pick2=jeans \cap pick3=\mathbf{legging}) = {6\over22} * {7\over23} * {5\over24}$

When looking at the answer, the book is claiming that $3  P(C)$ is the answer. In this case, the multiplication results turns out to be the same. But how do i know instinctively to just pick one from $P(A), P(B) or P(C)$ and multiply it by 3? I cant seem to wrap my head around it. Is it just by looking at the numerators ?(different set of permutation of numerators over the same denominators)

Comment: Each possible ordering of three students has the same probability.

Comment: Yes, I get that from doing the multiplication manually. But without that, how would I know they are the same?

Comment: This is just the assumption on the draw.  If it is false, then the conclusion will be very different.  If, say, you are choosing all the girls ahead of the boys then the probability will be very different.

Comment: I think this is a standard problem of precision of language in these things.  If you assume that "random" means that each student is equally likely to be chosen at any time, then show (as an exercise) that choosing $x,y,z$ has the same probability as choosing  $a,b,c$ for any other three students (or re-ordering of the first collection).

Comment: In math, there is often more than one way to do a problem. You used a different approach than the book. There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @user2773013: I asked very similar question a while back and received a number of good explanations, check it out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3192310/drawing-without-replacement-why-is-the-order-of-draw-irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

7+ 4+ 8= 19 so 24- 19= 5 students ("the rest") are wearing leggings.  The probability of choosing a student wearing leggings at random is  5/24.  Given that there are 23 students left, 7 of them wearing jeans.  The probability the second student chosen is wearing jeans is 7/23.  Given that there are 22 students left, 6 of them wearing jeans.  The probability that the third student chosen is wearing jeans is 6/22= 3/11.  The probability students wearing "leggings, jeans, jeans" are chosen **in that order** is (5/24)(7/23)(3/11).

The ways of ordering 3 **distinct** things is 3!= 6 but here the two students wearing jeans are not distinct.  Writing "L" for leggings and "J" for jeans the different orders are "JLL", "LJL", and "LLJ".  There are 3 ($\frac{3!}{2!1!}$) different orders, all with the same probability, (5/24)(7/23)(3/11), so the probability of choosing "one student wearing leggings, two wearing jeans" is 3(5/24)(7/23)(3/11)= 105/2024 which is about 0.052.

In a classroom with 24 students, 7 students are wearing jeans, 4 are wearing shorts, 8 are wearing skirts, and the rest are wearing leggings. If we randomly select 3 students without replacement, what is the probability that one of the selected students is wearing leggings and the other two are wearing jeans?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that:
$$ P(A) = P(B) = P(C) $$
This implies that
   $$ 3P(C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) $$

Comment: I guess my problem is more like how do you know that P(A) = P(B) = P(C) without actually doing the calculation, which what the solution seems to be doing.