# Order of picking items in Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

This may have been answered before, I just can't word my question properly in order to find it...

Given 5 red balls and 8 black balls, we need to pick 9 balls.

Are these two questions equivalent, if so, why?

- In how many ways can I **firstly** pick 3 red balls **and then** 6
  black balls.
- In how many ways can I pick 3 red balls **and** 6 black balls.

Knowing I can't reuse a ball, and order matters.

My solution to the second question:

Pick 3 places for red balls, $\binom{5}{3} \times3!$

Pick 6 places for black balls $\binom{8}{6} \times 6!$

Thus, $3!\times\binom{5}{3}\times6!\times\binom{8}{6}$.

Comment: Can you describe two different ways to "firstly pick 3 red balls and then 6 black balls."  What is observable and free to change in that description?

Comment: No, there is only one way  (in terms of "outer" order), I am free to change the balls inside.

Comment: Typically unless stated otherwise picking balls and picking cards and such are done simultaneously and so order of selection is irrelevant unless said otherwise.  It is stated here that order matters however.  That said, "pick 3 red balls and 6 black balls" is often interpreted to be the phrase "pick 3 red balls and 6 black balls **in any order**" which would allow for instance picking a red then a black then two more reds then five more blacks.  This is in comparison to the first phrase "pick 3 reds *and then* 6 black" where we specifically want the first three to be red and so on...

Comment: Is the change of "balls inside" observable?

Comment: @EricTowers No, since they are identical

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3192310/drawing-without-replacement-why-is-the-order-of-draw-irrelevant

Comment: Wait... "*no since they are identical*"  Who said that?  That completely changes the problem then and is not the common problem to work with.  Are you saying that there is one and only one possible outcome we want to count for the first problem?  For what reason would we have been told that we had $8$ black balls available from which to choose?  Are you saying that if that $8$ were changed to $800000000$ we would still only have one outcome?

Comment: @JMoravitz this was my thought process, according to a solution to that problem, they solve it like they are the same two questions.

Comment: Under the standard interpretation of the problems they are not at all the same and your interpretation from what you have shared so far does not match the standard interpretation of the problem either.  Even if the balls were identical, this question becomes almost meaningless to ask since if we were to try to answer the related question in probability about the chance of having drawn balls matching the desired description we would have forced uniqueness on the balls in order to help facilitate easier calculations.

Comment: As for your attempt at a calculation shown, first, you have an out of place $5$ appearing despite no $5$'s appearing in the problem statement.  Surely, that should have been the number of red balls available from which to choose which would be $4$ instead.  $\binom{4}{3}3!\binom{8}{6}6!$ is the number of ways to pick in sequence a red, then a red, then a red, then a black, then a black, then... then a black where each ball is distinct and order matters and would have been the answer to the first question.

Comment: @JMoravitz after thinking it through, yes the balls are certainly different, as you said before if they were identical it would be a different question entirely, sorry my bad.

Comment: The answer to the second question is the previous *times an additional factor of* $\binom{9}{3}$ corresponding to the number of ways we could mix colors further, such as red,black,red,black,red,black,black,black,... or black,black,black,red,red,red,black,black,... etc... for a grand total of $\binom{9}{3}\binom{4}{3}3!\binom{8}{6}6!$  The problem where the balls were all identical apart from color the answer to the first would have just been $1$ and to the second would have just been $\binom{9}{3}$ but these calculations are again hardly useful

Comment: Note: $\dfrac{\binom{9}{3}\binom{4}{3}3!\binom{8}{6}6!}{\binom{12}{9}9!}=\dfrac{\binom{4}{3}\binom{8}{6}}{\binom{12}{9}}$, so the probability question of asking the probability of us drawing three red and six black in any order gives the same answer whether we treated the sample space as order relevant or whether instead we treated the sample space as order irrelevant.

Comment: @JMoravitz Why would I want to mix things further, since am looking for one distinct order? shouldn't I divide by \binom{9}{3}

Comment: Because the original expression of $\binom{4}{3}3!\binom{8}{6}6!$ only counted the outcomes where it was very specifically red, red, red, black, black, black, black, black, black.  It failed to count any of the other outcomes which also qualify as having drawn three red and six black in any order such as having drawn a red, then a black, then a red, then a black, etc...  There are $\binom{9}{3}$ ways to arrange three $R$'s and six $B$'s in a row, and for each of these ways of arranging there are $\binom{4}{3}3!\binom{8}{6}6!$ ways of having chosen balls in that specific order, so we multiply.

Comment: Got it, got it, thank you so much for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should relate your query to *probability* rather than *number of ways.* It is there that I've seen students err.

If the order is specified, P(3 red followed by 6 black) would be
$\frac5{13}\frac4{12}\frac3{11}\frac8{10}\frac79\frac68\frac57\frac46\frac35$

but often, when the draws are to be in an unspecified order, it is mistakenly computed as above, whereas of course it needs to be multiplied by $\frac{9!}{3!6!},$
or better computed as$\dfrac{\binom53\binom86}{\binom{13}9}$

And conversely, when sometimes a **specified** order is given, the formula
$\dfrac{\binom53\binom86}{\binom{13}9}$ is used whereas, of course, it needs to be *divided* by $\frac{9!}{3!6!}$

If you ask for the *number of ways* draws can be made with  specified order and unspecified order, the issue becomes quite murky as you can see from the variety of opinions.

---

**PS:**

You write "This may have been answered before,..", I would like to add that I have never seen this **asked** ever !

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually the question is from a Probability course, I don't know why I didn't relate my query there also....
If I understood correctly the expression \dfrac{\binom53\binom86}{\binom{13}9} represents a specified order, so when multiplying by '\frac{9!}{3!6!}' you are simply counting all the other options to order the objects, correct?

Comment: No, $\dfrac{\binom53\binom86}{\binom{13}9}$ represents all possible orders, while $\frac5{13}\frac4{12}...$ represents the *Pr* of $3$ red followed by $6$ black, and needs to be multiplied by $\frac{9!}{3!6!}$ to generate all possible orders.

Comment: So we can calculate the **probability** of the event to happen, but **not** in how many ways we can get said event?

Comment: The question is relating to a hypergeometric distribution (= drawing without replacement). Unless related to probability calculation, the interpretation of "number of ways" becomes debatable as can be seen by the numerous comments and answer of @Henry.

Comment: The same or similar question has appeared again, and I have come to an understanding of what the book wants. You can have a look.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4086880/the-number-of-ways-of-selecting-5-white-balls-and-4-black-balls/4086949#4086949

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what counts as different.

Perhaps the answer to (1) is $1$ and to (2) is ${3+6 \choose 3}=84$

But I would find that unhelpful, and would prefer the answer to (1) to be

$$5\times 4 \times 3 \times  8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 =\frac{5! \,8!}{(5-3)!(8-6)!} = 1209600$$

which is your answer to the second question, though I think that (2) should  still be ${3+6 \choose 3}$ times this, i.e. $9!{5\choose 3}{8 \choose 6} = 101606400$

This latter approach makes calculating probabilities possible: the total number of ways of choosing $9$ balls this way is $\frac{13!}{(13-9)!}$ making the probability of drawing $3$ red and $6$ black in any order $\dfrac{{5 \choose 3}{8\choose 6}}{13 \choose 9}$, the usual hypergeometric probability.  The first approach would not facilitate this calculation