# The number of ways of selecting 5 white balls and 4 black balls

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

I have urn with 5 white balls and 4 black balls.

The balls are non-distinct ( there aren't numbers on it, but every ball have one color: white or black, so they are a little distinct - there is difference between black and white ball ).

In how many ways I can take from urn 3 balls, which are white? I take all balls in the same moment.

When I have ditinct balls, this exercise is very simple. For example white balls have numbers ( 1-5 ) on it. I can create 10 combinations for example {1,2,3} , {2,3,4}. So this is 5 choose 3.

But what if I have non-distinct balls? For me I have only one way to do this. When I take 3 balls and all balls are white, next I return to urn all balls and repeat process and I get 3 white balls and I don't know they are the same, which were in first draw. All white balls are non-distinct, so In every draw when I get 3 white balls I will have { White, White, White }.

Am I right?

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you asking, say, "If I draw three balls without replacement, what is the probability that they are all white?"

Comment: @lulu This is not a question about probability, but about combinatorics. The exercise which I have in my book is: In the urn there are 5 white balls and 4 black balls. How many ways can you take 3 balls from the urn to receive A) 3 white balls ( I ask about it ) B) 3 black balls C) 1 black and 2 white etc. The answer to A is 5 choose 3.

Comment: Yes, but that is not clear.  How do you distinguish between two different such draws?  I mean..the answer to your question could be "$1$  since all such draws are equivalent."  or it could be "$\binom 53$ since there are five white balls in total and you seek to draw three of them."

Comment: To defend the answer $\binom 53$ one acknowledges that the white balls, which may look alike, are not in fact exactly the same.   That's certainly a defensible answer.

Comment: @lulu So there is a difference between distinguish  and non-distinguish balls? The answer is the same ( If I accepted answer from my book ).

Comment: It's just a matter of being clear which thing you mean.  If you say "two draws are the same if they look the same", then the answer is $1$.  But if you are trying to compute, say, the probability, then you want to acknowledge that the balls are in fact different, even if the differences aren't apparent to the naked eye.

Comment: 'I take all balls in the same moment' - do you mean sampling without replacement?

Comment: @Alex No. I mean that I don't take balls individually. I put my hand to urn, take 3 balls at the same moment, so I can't say " the first ball which I taken was..., the second ball which I taken was.... ).

Comment: OK, so for the second ball would the probability be $\frac{5}{9}$ or $\frac{4}{8}$?

Comment: @Alex I take 3 balls in the same moment ( I have big hand ), so I don't know which ball is a second ball :)

Comment: @lulu But when I have exercise: I have n non-distinguish balls and n non-distinguish bins. I have to put all balls to all bins ( one ball to one bin ). I can do that only in one way. So what is a difference between current and this exercise?

Comment: As I say, it's just a matter of being clear what you intend.  If, inserad of an urn we have a machine that magically generates balls (identical save for color) then there is only way to get three whites out of the first three draws, namely $WWW$.

Comment: @lulu inserad? What it means? I try use translator, but don't get any word :)

Comment: Typo.  Should have been "instead".

Comment: If it helps:  I think it's fair to say that in "most" contexts one wants to retain some individuality in the balls, so $\binom 53$ is more likely to be what is intended.  But some times one only wants to describe the possible outcomes of the draws, in which case there are exactly $4$, as the number of white calls could be anything from $0$ to $3$.   To stress, however, those $4$ outcomes are not equally probable.

Comment: @lulu So balls are non-distinguish , but I treat it like distinguish ?

Comment: See the answer I have posted. The balls are distinguishable only by color, and still you get the same answer in the interpretation I have given.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I understand what the question is asking.

You could in a blind draw of $3$ balls  have drawn $(0W,3B), (1W,2B), (2W,1B)\; or\; (3W,0W)$

These are all the  possibilities.

If you add up $\binom50\binom43 + \binom51\binom42 +....  \binom53\binom40$, the answer will come out to be $84$, which is ( and has to be) the same as $\binom93$

So in this context, the question is asking  how many ways can you draw all $3$ as white, for which the answer is $\binom53\binom40 = \binom53$

The answer for drawing $3$ black balls is similarly $\binom43$ and so on.

**Note:**
*Distinguishability only by color and a blind draw of all three balls simultaneously is enough to give these results.*