# How do I find number of ways to choose 10 cards from a set of 7 blue and 8 red cards

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

If given a set of $7$ blue cards and $8$ red cards and asked to pick $10$ at random how do I figure out how many possible ways there are to select those cards? I got a bit stumped after realizing $2^{10}$ doesn't really help here and I'm not sure how to calculate it in a way that would account for the fact that you can run out of one type of card. I also would like to know how to figure out the number of ways to select $5$ red and $5$ blue cards exactly.

Thank you for any help

Edit to clarify:
The cards are identical but the order they are drawn is important to the question. For example, B B B B B R R R R R and R R R R R B B B B B would count as $2$ ways to draw the cards.

Comment: Are all cards different (even of the same color)? If so, why did you not go with $15 \choose 10$? If cards of same color are identical then there are only $6$ ways (starting with $2$ blue cards or $3$, ... or $7$)

Comment: Are cards of a certain color distinguishable i.e. can you distinguish a certain blue card from another blue card? Also does the order of drawing matter in this problem i.e. do you want to just calculate the number of hands or the number of ways to sequentially draw $10$ cards?

Comment: Based on your edit, if you had enough number of both cards $2^{10}$ would have done it. Now subtract where there are $9$ of red cards or $10$ of red cards. Number of ways for $9$ red cards is $10$ and number of ways for $10$ red cards is $1$ . So the first one should be $2^{10} - 10 - 1$.

Comment: You say "The cards are identical but the order they are drawn is important to the question." Do you mean **all** cards are to be treated as identical or that *cards of a particular color* are identical ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Please see my comments following both answers.

Comment: @user2661923: I have given my comments as an answer as it was becoming long.

Answer (score 3):

First, consider the case without any restriction i.e. you can choose at most $10$ red cards. As you figured out, this can be done in $2^{10}$ ways.

Now back to our original question, we overcounted the cases when there are $10$ or $9$ red cards and the cases when there are $10$ or $9$ or $8$ blue cards. We can choose $10$ red cards in only one way. When we chose $9$ red cards, there were $10$ spaces between each consecutive red cards and we can place a blue card in each space. Similarly, we get that there are $1$ and $10$ ways when there are $9$ or $10$ blue cards. For the case when there are $8$ blue cards, we use [stars and bars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to see that there are $\binom{10}{2}$ ways. So the answer would be $2^{10}-2(10+1)-\binom{10}{2}$.

This also matches with Syam's answer.

---

A lot of controversies has happened regarding the question. But if we think about the configuration of the cards, we will see that the answer will be less than $2^{10}$. Also making the problem smaller and listing all possible configurations is a good way to check the answers.

Comment: Interesting: now there are three separate viewpoints as to what the right answer is.  Sort of like a 3 cornered duel.

Comment: I believe you also overcounted the cases where there are 8, 9, or 10 blue cards.

Comment: The answer would be identical to the one given by Syam after the correction.

Comment: @LearningMathematics Ah, fixed it. I hope it's okay now. Thanks.

Comment: @Unknown: If you read the question carefully, it starts with **choose** in the header, **pick** in the first line and **select** a bit later. The permutation part has been added as an afterthought which leads me to believe that the intention is to **choose** first and **then** permute each **selection**, not just permute.

Comment: @trueblueanil I don't think the wording of the question is important here. Rather I think the example OP provided at the last of his question is important, that is $R \ R \ R\ R\ R\ B \ B\ B\ B\ B$ and $B\ B\ B\ B\ B\ R\ R\ R\ R\ R$ are different. Also, I think choosing first assumes that the cards of same color are distinguishable which is not the case. A lot of debate has been happened between Ethan and user2661923 on this. But I still believe choosing the cards first is somehow not the case. So by the end of the day, let's agree to disagree :-)

Comment: @Unknown: Ok, I understand, the question *is* ambiguous, but such debates once in a while is fun :-)

Answer (score 2):

Do it by listing down the possible ways.
For example, we can choose

- 7B and 3R cards --> $(10!)$/$(7!3!)$
- 6B and 4R cards --> $(10!)$/$(6!4!)$
- 5B and 5R cards --> $(10!)$/$(5!5!)$- This answers the last part of the question
- 4B and 6R cards -->  $(10!)$/$(4!6!)$
- 3B and 7R cards --> $(10!)$/$(3!7!)$
- 2B and 8R cards --> $(10!)$/$(2!8!)$

Comment: This is incorrect. You need to first select which of the blues and reds you would like first.

Comment: But all the reds are identical, and it does not matter which of the red cards we pick

Comment: It does not matter, but you still have to pick them nonetheless. They are not going to "appear in front of your face magically" (for lack of better phrasing). Saying they are identical simply means we account for this fact in their arrangement (which you have done by dividing). For example, your $\frac {10!} {7!3!}$ would work if I already gave you exactly $7$ blue balls and $3$ red balls, but that is not the case here. We always start off with $7$ blue balls and $8$ red balls.

Comment: @EthanMark I think that the answer of Syam Manoj Kumar Paila is right and you are mistaken.  See my comment following your answer.  +1 to his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is still a little unclear, but I suppose you mean that *within* the blue cards, all of them are identical and *within* the red cards, all of them are identical, not that *all* of the cards are identical (since if it was to be that *all* of the cards are identical, then there really is no point in the question specifying the colours  - it could simply have said $15$ identical cards).

Now, if the former is true, then when picking $10$ random cards out of the $15$, it would be best to consider cases with respect to the blue cards (you can obviously do the same with respect to the red cards). Clearly, we have 6 cases - $7$ blue and $3$ red, $6$ blue and $4$ red and so on... Thus, we can just find the number of possible arrangements for each case and add them all up.

For example, the first case would give $$\binom 7 7 \binom 8 3 \frac {10!} {7! 3!},$$ where we choose $7$ out of $7$ (i.e. all) of the blues, $3$ out of $8$ of the reds and then arrange them all in a line (i.e. $10!$), but remembering also that same-coloured balls are identical (i.e. divide by $7!3!$).

You can find the number of possible arrangements for the rest of the cases in a similar fashion and answer your second part as well.

P.S. Welcome to Math SE! If this answer has helped you, please give it an upvote and the tick :)

**Edit**

As noted in the long discussion under my answer and corroborated with another answer, it is a **MUST** to first choose how many blue and red balls you want, because in the question, we are given more blue and red balls than we need. It is not that we are differentiating between each blue and each red ball (the question has indicated that they are identical within the colours) - we are simply “throwing away” the excess of each type of ball which we do not need. Identicality is accounted for in the permutations, not when we are choosing the number of each type of ball.

Comment: To illustrate why I think that you are wrong, consider the specific case of 7 blue and 3 red.  The whole point of coloring the cards is to consider all red cards to be indistinguishable, and likewise all blue cards.  In fact, the OP edited his question to say just that.  There are only $\binom{10}{3} = \binom{10}{7}$ different orderings of the cards, based on which of the $10$ slots represents the choice of a blue card.  ...see next comment

Comment: Just to spell it out, all selections that  are represented by b-b-b-r-r-r-r-r-r-r are represented by a **single** ordering, regardless of which specific blue cards from the 8 are used.  Therefore, -1 to your answer.  Please address a comment to me if you wish to discuss this or if you edit your answer.

Comment: Correction to my first comment.  I intended r-r-r-b-b-b-b-b-b-b.  Okay, let's play this game.  Suppose we label the balls $r_1, \cdots, r_8, b_1, \cdots, b_7. $ I contend that $r_1, r_2, r_3, b_1, \cdots, b_7$ is the same distribution as $r_1, r_2, r_4, b_1, \cdots, b_7.$  Since cards of a specific color are indistinuishable, you won't be able to tell those two orderings apart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128844/discussion-between-user2661923-and-ethan-mark).

Comment: I have invited you to chat.

Comment: @user2661924 Correction noted, but that is irrelevant because you are still missing my point. I **totally and fully** agree with you that $r_1, r_2, r_3, b_1, \dots, b_7$ and $r_1, r_2, r_4, b_1, \dots, b_7$ are exactly the same, so I am not sure what you are contending about. My point is that you first need the specific amount of reds and blues before you can even say this. To be more specific, if I told you have $3$ red and $7$ blues, your statement automatically holds. However, you do not - you currently have $7$ blues and $8$ reds.

Comment: In the final answer, the number of reds will range from $3$ thru $8$.  Regardless of how many reds there are to choose from there are only $\binom{10}{r}$ distributions that involve $r$ reds.  Even if there were $1000$ reds instead of only $8$, the only issue is how many reds show out of the $10$, and where are they placed.  Answer must be $\sum_{i=3}^{8} \binom{10}{i}.$

Comment: @user2661923 I disagree. If we had $1000$ reds and needed $8$ in a line, we would have $\binom {1000} 8$ ways to do so (we just need *any* $8$). We simply do not have to do any arrangement in this case since all $8$ are identical. Well, clearly we are at a standstill here. I doubt anything would come out from continuing this any further, so I would not mind waiting for other esteemed users to chance upon our discussion and give their valuable inputs.

Comment: I invited true blue anil to participate.  I also am curious what he, or anyone else has to say.  I hope I am flagged when someone else contributes.

Comment: @EthanMark: I have given my comments in an answer as it was becoming long. (+1)

Comment: @user2661923: I understand the point you are raising, since there is no overt link of this question to probability, but see my PPS which gives a question where similar confusion was arising

Comment: @trueblueanil commenting here so that Ethan Mark now reads it; and I have already reversed my downvote of his answer.  While your interpretation strikes me as bizarre, after reading the cited link, you are certainly not alone in your (and Ethan Mark's) interpretation.  Nor am I alone in my interpretation.  Therefore, I don't see how I can continue to insist that you and Ethan Mark are wrong.  Yet another case of brevity is the soul of poorly (i.e. ambiguously) worded math problems.

Comment: @EthanMark I disagree with your answer. As my defense, I would say that the configuration of the cards will be of the form $C \ C \ C \ C \ C \ C \ C \ C \ C \ C$ where each $C$ can be replaced with either $R$ or $B$. Without restriction the answer would be $2^{10}$, and the answer to the original problem will be less than that. But in your answer in the first case, the number of ways is $\binom{7}{7}\binom{8}{3}\frac{10!}{7!3!}=6720$ which is way greater than $2^{10}$. So, I think you are highly overcounting.

Comment: @Unknown I would say this is incorrect as well, because if this were a probability question (I know it is not but we can always turn it into one), then your method is akin to saying that there is equal probability in choosing a red or blue card. However, this is not true (we have more reds than blue). In other words, this is not a “symmetric” counting problem. Note that I may not be accurately explaining this because I was never too familiar with the “$2^{\mathrm{something}}$” argument when it came to permutations and combinations.

Comment: @EthanMark The answer given by Unknown is the same as user2661923 after some corrections (see my comments under his post). Also, whether the possibilities of different combinations are the same is not an issue here.

Comment: So far as the count is concerned, it can be seen that $\binom77\binom83 + \binom76\binom84 +...\binom72\binom88 = \binom{15}{10}$, so there is no overcount. And each such combination can be permuted.

Comment: The above approach assumes that it is a hidden probability problem, or that for convenience we have numbered each ball and all possible ways of getting the combo through blind draws are counted. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4086880/the-number-of-ways-of-selecting-5-white-balls-and-4-black-balls/4086949#4086949

Answer (score 2):

Since controversy has arisen, I thought it best to write it as an answer.

I take it that it is settled that cards of the same color are identical, ie cards are distinguished only by color.

We consider the case of $7$ blue, $3$ red

- firstly assume that cards are numbered $b_1,b_2,... r_1,r_2...$ etc
- It is clear that they can be *chosen and permuted* in $\binom77\binom{8}310!$ ways
- But in reality, all blue cards are identical, and so are all red cards, so we remove duplication of permutations to finally get
  $\binom77\binom{8}3\frac{10!}{7!3!}$ as the answer

**PS:**

In hypergeometric problems with red balls, blue balls, yellow balls, etc each ball is generally given a fictitious identity, which is later on erased by removing permutations within the same color.

**PPS**

Some time back, there were a couple of questions about "how many ways" balls of varying colors could be drawn. There was quite a lot of controversy on those, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4086880/the-number-of-ways-of-selecting-5-white-balls-and-4-black-balls/4086949#4086949) is one example, the other was even funnier. The book answers tallied with the concept matching the method used in calculating probability.

Comment: @EthanMark Although I disagree with both you and true blue anil, I have added a period to the end of your answer to unlock scoring, and then upvoted your answer.  My disagreement continues.  Since (for example) red cards are indistinguishable, I do not think one is supposed to differentiate between which red cards are selected.

Comment: @user2661924 We are not differentiating anything here - this is the part you need to get. We are simply selecting how many reds and blues we want. If you are stuck up with how I have explained it, you can think of it in the following way as well - we have to “throw away” those balls which we do not want for each specific case (i.e. the excess number of each type of ball). Both schools of thought are equivalent. I hope you will be convinced with time.

Comment: That is to say that there are 5 ways to choose two balls from one red ball and two blue balls? I found it counterintuitive.

Comment: @LearningMathematics: If you do blind draws of two from numbered balls, you would get $3$ combos, viz $(RB_1,RB_2,B_1B_2)$

Comment: Yes, that is also my answer. But when I try to use your way, it gives $\binom11\binom21\frac{2!}{1!1!} + \binom10\binom22\frac{2!}{0!2!} = 5$ as an answer. But that's just due to a different interpretation of the problem.